# Mostrar errores cuando ejecutas un script de Python desde php con system, en un hosting compartido

Tags: php, python

Estoy ejecutando un script de Python desde php de esta forma,

> $mystring = system('python test.py', $retval);

y funciona, sólo que me gustaría poder ver los errores del script de Python. Es posible? Los "print" de Python por ejemplo se ven, pero los errores del script de Python no, esta claramente fallando al importar un modulo porque la ejecucion se para ahi y no me muestra ningun error en pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$mystring = system("python test.py 2>&1", $retval);
```

Si no te funciona, por favor, indica el SO.

Aunque lo ideal sería que primero depurases el script de Python desde tu terminal y una vez que funcione y conozcas las dependencias, versión de python,..., vayas al hosting compartido, instales las dependencias y subas el script...